# Export email from mysql with php, but export all my php page

Tags: php, mysql, csv, download, export

I'd like to export my contact email, stored in mysql database with a script.
I need to export my email in csv file.

But, when the page reload, the file is downloading and into this file i have all my php page!

```
<?php
if(IsSet($_POST['export_test'])){
    // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

    // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    // output the column headings
    fputcsv($output, array('E-mail'));

    // fetch the data
    $string = "SELECT Email FROM address";
    $query = mysql_query($string);

    // loop over the rows, outputting them
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) fputcsv($output, $row);
}
?>
```

in data.csv i can see all my page

```
(<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon/advancedsettings.png" type="image/x-icon" />.....)
```

thank you

Comment: `die(); //after while loop`

Comment: You have a { missing after while

Comment: @Mihai curly braces are not required for single line loop constructs

Comment: Can you show the connection?

Comment: have you tried my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the csv file and writing some content and then executing the query. Then how can you get the emails as output?. Try this code this will give the exact result which you need

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","table_name");// connection to db
if(isset($_POST['export_test'])){
$sql="select email from address";// select query 
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$line .= "\n"; // new line 
$filename='email.csv';// create csv file if dosent exist 
$fp = fopen($filename, "w");// open the csv file to write 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
$line = "";
$comma = "";
$line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $row['email']) . '",';
$comma = ",";
$line .= "\n";
fputs($fp, $line); // put the line into csv 
}
fclose($fp);
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');// to download the email.csv
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=email.csv');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem :)

I put my script in a external php file, and it works!
before my script was on top of my page and was not working

thank you!